# Excel apply timestamp when macro was ran

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a email list with To, CC and BCC columns. When the checkbox is TRUE then it will add the email to that specific line in Outlook.

What I would like to do is when the Macro is ran then apply a timestamp to a cell for only the TRUE checkboxes in column "J".

This is what I am working with.

```
Sub SendEmail()

' Set up outlook objects for emailing

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

' Body text for the email
Dim strbody As String
strbody = ""

' Strings to contain the email addresses
Dim sendTo As String
sendTo = ""
Dim sendCC As String
sendCC = ""
Dim sendBCC As String
sendBCC = ""

' The cell containing the email address (loop variable)
Dim emailCell As Range

With ActiveSheet

    ' Cycle through email addresses, from B3 to one before next blank cell in column
    For Each emailCell In .Range("B3", .Range("B3").End(xlDown))

        ' Check each TRUE/FALSE column in same row, add email addresses accordingly

        If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "E").Text = "TRUE" Then

            sendTo = sendTo & "; " & emailCell.Text

        End If

        If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "G").Text = "TRUE" Then

            sendCC = sendCC & "; " & emailCell.Text

        End If

        If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "I").Text = "TRUE" Then

            sendBCC = sendBCC & "; " & emailCell.Text

        End If

    Next emailCell

End With

' Generate email in outlook objects defined above
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = sendTo
    .CC = sendCC
    .BCC = sendBCC
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    .Display
    ' If you don't want to display the email before sending it,
    ' simply use .Send instead of .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: You talk about checkboxes, but your code concerns TRUE values in cells. Are there checkboxes. If not, and the cells are triggering the action, is it triggered if just one of the three cells is TRUE? How detailed should the timestamp be: day? second? something else?

Comment: I just changed it to a wingding code that when cell is touched then it toggles between two wingding characters that look like an uncheck box and a checked one. Right now any one can be checked and it will add that email in that spot. so you could send it to yourself and Cc and Bcc yourself. I am looking for current day and time for when the macro was ran. Thx

Comment: If you are _"looking for current day and time for when the macro was ran"_ then it has nothing to do with the values of what you call "check boxes". Just choose a cell and enter something like =now(), the `pastevalue` that cell.

Comment: @EEM, the OP wants to add the timestamp at the time it's run. Your solution seems fine, but your statement that the OP shouldn't use checkboxes to determine whether to add the timestamp for that row seems wrong to me.

Comment: @DougGlancy, OP says that just wants to know when the macros was ran, that implies regardless of the outcome, so not need to check anything else....

Comment: @EEM, it specifically says for rows with TRUE.

Comment: @DougGlancy Also specifically says _" I am looking for current day and time for when the macro was ran. Thx"_ have you seen 2nd comment.

Comment: @EEM, yes I read that. Current day, etc., is a timestamp, so it seems like we're talking about the same thing there. It's the TRUE part that I disagree with you on. I guess we'll find out when the OP comes back.

Comment: @DougGlancy Regardless of what the OP says, which I'm agree with you on OP's intention, I'm referring to what was written and highlighting the contradiction... One key part of programming is to ensure of getting accurate and clear requirements. Yet that has to do with standards...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131277/discussion-between-doug-glancy-and-eem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds a timestamp if any of the three columns E,G or I are TRUE for that row. The timestamp is in descending order from year to second. You can change that by altering the format.

If you want the timestamps to be text then format the column first (or in your code). If column J isn't formatted as text then the timestamp will be an actual DateTime and will appear in whatever format Excel thinks it should.

```
If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "E") OR .Cells(emailCell.Row, "G") OR .Cells(emailCell.Row, "I") Then
   .Cells(emailCell.row, "J").Value = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
End If
```

Comment: No need to use `Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")` if entering as number, `.Value = Now()` produces the same result, one way of entering as text is adding “Chr(39) & “ to the formula (i.e. `
= Chr(39) & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Thanks, but not sure where to place this in my code? Most places that I tried it gives me an error "Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference" then it highlights the first ".Cells". If I place it after the "IF .Cells ... Row, "I") and before the ending "End If" statement for that object then the original code works but no timestamp.

Comment: You'd put it at the end of the For/Next loop, after the last IF and before the Next. I realized I left in the bit about 'SendTo` which is a duplicate, so removed that. However, that doesn't affect it.

Comment: @DougGlancy I had to add a .Text = "R" at the end of each of your emailcell.row statements. then it works like a charm, Thanks so much :)

Comment: So the values weren't actually TRUE or FALSE? That would have been helpful to know :-). Anyways, you're welcome, I'm glad it worked.

Comment: They were true and false but changed it to a wingdings code, so "R" = Checkmark. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try

```
If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "J").Text = "TRUE" Then
    sendTo = sendTo & "; " & emailCell.Text
   .cells(emailcell.row, column).value = hour(now) & ":" & minute(now)
End If
```

Comment: I might not understand correctly, but I think the OP wants a timestamp in Column J if E, G, or I in that row are TRUE.

Comment: @DougGlancy You are correct. need to fill out timestamp in J3 if email from E3, G3 or I3 is checked. (Row 3 being an example)

Comment: @EEM, what makes it volatile? It's part of a larger Sub, i.e., the OP's posted code.

Comment: @DougGlancy Ooops, Sorry mi mistake, I somehow (wrongly) saw it as enter as a formula, not the actual value. apologies....

Answer (score 0):

```
If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "D").Text = "R" Or .Cells(emailCell.Row, "E").Text = "R" Or .Cells(emailCell.Row, "F").Text = "R" Then
   .Cells(emailCell.Row, "G").Value = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")
End If
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it's problematic that your question and answer test for different values: TRUE and "R". Also, it's probably not necessary, since the main logic and the discussion of using "R" rather than TRUE is addressed in the comments to my accepted answer. I'd consider deleting this.